# Is rephrased sentence for "subject to" correct?

Tags: meaning

I originally had "Changes which a Product shall be **subject to** as part of its life cycle", but felt that using "subject to" was bad form and rephrased the sentence as follows:

> Changes to which a Product shall be subject as part of its life cycle.

Is the above correct?  Somehow, "subject to" sounds better, although it may be wrong.  I feel separating the two words leads to loss of the meaning.

PS: How would I tag this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first version strikes me as being more approachable. The second is stiffer, more formal and more old-fashioned in tone.

I'd suggest *syntax* as being a suitable tag, but I'll defer to the more long-standing members of the forum regarding what would be the most appropriate label(s).

Comment: +1 Thanks, that's exactly what I thought as well.  So, "subject to" is not necessarily wrong in the modern world of English?

Comment: @Sabuncu - No; in fact, today it would be generally regarded as more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

"Subject to" is not wrong, but it doesn't seem to fit pretty well with the formality of your wording.

"Shall," "subject to," and "cycle" are all formal terms, and so should be the grammar that comes along.

And so, I'd go for:

> *Changes **to which** a product shall be subject as part of its life cycle*...

Consider this other example:

> *The classification [to which](http://facultynh.syr.edu/bjsheeha/ADV%20206/Moriarty%20Materials/Test%20Bank/moriarty_adv-imc9_tif_ch2.doc) a product is assigned is known as...*